# Calling js login API. on entering correct credential i can login but on wrong i want alert & message should be from API response but unable to get it

Tags: javascript, authentication

```js
function userlogin(){   
  var success = "";
  var message = "";
  var data = "";
  var access_token = "";
  var refresh_token = "";
  $.ajax('http://43.204.97.29:5000/login', {
    type: 'POST', 
                
    data: { 
      username: document.getElementById("userName").value, 
      password: document.getElementById("password").value 
    },  
    success: function (server_response, status, xhr) {
      success=server_response.success;
      message=server_response.message;
      data = server_response.data;

      access_token=data.access;
      refresh_token=data.refresh;
      if(message="successfull"){
        document.cookie = "access_token=" + access_token + "; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        window.open("http://13.232.215.199/gameshield/dashboard.html","_self");
      }

    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, server_response) {                    
                    success=server_response.success;
                    if(success == "false"){   
                        message=server_response.message;
                        alert(message);
                    }
            }   
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="userlogin();" value="login" id="login">
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to tell us what the problem is. the title should be a brief description, with the bulk of the information in the body.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.